# Creating new variable based on substring in another variable in Python

Tags: python, pandas, string

I am trying to create a binary (yes/no) variable based on what is in a particular text string (in Python).

The data looks something like:

| Person ID | Test Result |
| --- | --- |
| 87 | No exercise induced ischaemia |
| 88 | Treadmill test induced increased BP |
| 89 | NORMAL test on treadmill |

and so on.

I need to pick out all the people who have "No exercise induced ischaemia".  Can anybody shed some light on how to do this, given I have about 20 columns in the real data set and about 14000 rows that need to be searched.

Here's an example dataframe for convenience

```
d = {'ID': [87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92], 'TestResult': ["No exercise induced ischaemia", "NORMAL test on treadmill",  "No exercise induced ischaemia", "treadmill induced ischaemia", "NORMAL test on treadmill", "No exercise induced ischaemia"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I've tried things like

```
df['NegTest'] = df[df.TestResult.str.contains('No exercise induced ischaemia',case=True)]
```

with no luck.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you just need to drop the outer `df[]` on the right hand side? Just assign the result of `.str.contains()`. That's a bool Series.

Comment: Just `df['NegTest'] = df.TestResult.str.contains('No exercise induced ischaemia',case=True)` will give you a new column of bools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close. Just use `np.where` to actually generate the yes/no:

```
df['NegTest'] = np.where(df.TestResult.str.contains('No exercise induced ischaemia', case=True), 'yes', 'no')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   ID                     TestResult NegTest
0  87  No exercise induced ischaemia     yes
1  88       NORMAL test on treadmill      no
2  89  No exercise induced ischaemia     yes
3  90    treadmill induced ischaemia      no
4  91       NORMAL test on treadmill      no
5  92  No exercise induced ischaemia     yes
```

If you want it to just be True/False, you can even skip `np.where`:

```
df['NegTest'] = df.TestResult.str.contains('No exercise induced ischaemia', case=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   ID                     TestResult  NegTest
0  87  No exercise induced ischaemia     True
1  88       NORMAL test on treadmill    False
2  89  No exercise induced ischaemia     True
3  90    treadmill induced ischaemia    False
4  91       NORMAL test on treadmill    False
5  92  No exercise induced ischaemia     True
```

Comment: Oh brilliant, I knew there had to be something missing!!  Thanks :)